# How to read a Parquet file into Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, blaze

How to read a modestly sized Parquet data-set into an in-memory Pandas DataFrame without setting up a cluster computing infrastructure such as Hadoop or Spark? This is only a moderate amount of data that I would like to read in-memory with a simple Python script on a laptop. The data does not reside on HDFS. It is either on the local file system or possibly in S3. I do not want to spin up and configure other services like Hadoop, Hive or Spark.

I thought Blaze/Odo would have made this possible: the Odo documentation mentions Parquet, but the examples seem all to be going through an external Hive runtime.

Comment: Do you happen to have the data openly available? My branch of python-parquet https://github.com/martindurant/parquet-python/tree/py3 had a pandas reader in parquet.rparquet, you could try it. There are many parquet constructs it cannot handle.

Comment: Wait for the Apache Arrow project that the Pandas author Wes Mckinney is part of. http://wesmckinney.com/blog/pandas-and-apache-arrow/ After it is done, users should be able to read in Parquet file directly from Pandas.

Comment: Since the question is closed as off-topic (but still the first result on Google) I have to answer in a comment.. You can now use pyarrow to read a parquet file and convert it to a pandas DataFrame: `import pyarrow.parquet as pq; df = pq.read_table('dataset.parq').to_pandas()`

Comment: Kinda annoyed that this question was closed. Spark and parquet are (still) relatively poorly documented. Am also looking for the answer to this.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/dask/fastparquet . For an introduction see https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/introducing-fastparquet .

Comment: Both the fastparquet and pyarrow libraries make it possible to read a parquet file into a pandas dataframe: https://github.com/dask/fastparquet and https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

Comment: @ogrisel it's open now

Comment: @DanielMahler consider updating the accepted answer

Answer (score 223, accepted):

pandas 0.21 introduces [new functions for Parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/io.html#io-parquet):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_parquet('example_pa.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_parquet('example_fp.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
```

The above link explains:

> These engines are very similar and should read/write nearly identical parquet format files. These libraries differ by having different underlying dependencies (fastparquet by using numba, while pyarrow uses a c-library).

Comment: For most of my data, 'fastparquet' is a bit faster.
Just in case `pd.read_parquet()` returns a problem with Snappy Error, run `conda install python-snappy` to install snappy.

Comment: I found pyarrow to be too difficult to install (both on my local windows machine and on a cloud linux machine). Even after the python-snappy fix, there were additional issues with the compiler as well as the error module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'compat'. fastparquet had no issues at all.

Comment: @Catbuilts You can use gzip if you don't have snappy.

Comment: can 'fastparquet' read ',snappy.parquet' file?

Comment: I had the opposite experience vs. @Seb. fastparquet had a bunch of issues, pyarrow was simple pip install and off I went

Answer (score 20):

Update: since the time I answered this there has been a lot of work on this look at Apache Arrow for a better read and write of parquet. Also: http://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-parquet-multithreading/

There is a python parquet reader that works relatively well: https://github.com/jcrobak/parquet-python

It will create python objects and then you will have to move them to a Pandas DataFrame so the process will be slower than `pd.read_csv` for example.

Comment: Actually there is pyarrow which allows both reads / writes: http://pyarrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parquet.html

Comment: I get a permission denied error when I try to follow your link, @bluszcz -- do you have an alternate?

Comment: parquet-python is much slower than alternatives such as fastparquet et pyarrow: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

Comment: `pd.read_parquet` is now part of pandas. The other answer should be marked as valid.

Answer (score 15):

Aside from pandas, Apache pyarrow also provides way to transform parquet to dataframe

The code is simple, just type:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pq.read_table(source=your_file_path).to_pandas()
```

For more information, see the document from Apache pyarrow [Reading and Writing Single Files](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html?highlight=to_pandas#reading-and-writing-single-files)

Answer (score 12):

## Parquet

### Step 1: Data to play with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'student': ['personA007', 'personB', 'x', 'personD', 'personE'],
    'marks': [20,10,22,21,22],
})
```

### Step 2: Save as Parquet

```
df.to_parquet('sample.parquet')
```

### Step 3: Read from Parquet

```
df = pd.read_parquet('sample.parquet')
```

Answer (score 4):

When writing to parquet, consider using brotli compression. I'm getting a 70% size reduction of 8GB file parquet file by using brotli compression. Brotli makes for a smaller file and faster read/writes than gzip, snappy, pickle. Although pickle can do tuples whereas parquet does not.

```
df.to_parquet('df.parquet.brotli',compression='brotli')
df = pd.read_parquet('df.parquet.brotli')
```

Answer (score 2):

Parquet files are always large. so read it using dask.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed
from fastparquet import ParquetFile
import glob

files = glob.glob('data/*.parquet')

@delayed
def load_chunk(path):
    return ParquetFile(path).to_pandas()

df = dd.from_delayed([load_chunk(f) for f in files])

df.compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the `.parquet` file named `data.parquet`

```
parquet_file = '../data.parquet'

open( parquet_file, 'w+' )
```

## Convert to Parquet

Assuming one has a dataframe `parquet_df` that one wants to save to the parquet file above, one can use [`pandas.to_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) (this function requires either the [fastparquet](https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet) or [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/) library) as follows

```
parquet_df.to_parquet(parquet_file)
```

## Read from Parquet

In order to read the parquet file into a dataframe `new_parquet_df`, one can use [`pandas.read_parquet()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) as follows

```
new_parquet_df = pd.read_parquet(parquet_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use python to get parquet data

1. install package
   `pip install pandas pyarrow`
2. read file

```py
def read_parquet(file):
    result = []
    data = pd.read_parquet(file)
    for index in data.index:
        res = data.loc[index].values[0:-1]
        result.append(res)
    print(len(result))


file = "./data.parquet"
read_parquet(file)
```

Comment: that is "pip install", not "pin install". I would fix it, but small changes are not allowed, despite that fact that a one letter change means the difference between a program not running with lots of confusion, and everything working.