# Apply Multiclass version of SVM classifier in sklearn library over data stored in SPARK Dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have saved spark dataframe using `df.write.parquet("filePath")` as a parquet file. I want to apply `Sklearn` SVM classifier over this dataframe columns as Multiclass SVM is absent in Spark `ML/MLLib` library.

I tried reading the saved data with `spark.read.parquet('FilePath')` and then converting it to pandas using `toPandas()`. However this conversion from spark `DataFrame` to pandas `DataFrame` is taking too much time as data is huge(81GB). Is it possible to directly read the saved SPARK `DataFrame` in pandas `DataFrame`.

If not, what will be the best way to proceed further?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a Parquet file into Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813815/how-to-read-a-parquet-file-into-pandas-dataframe)