# Python - read parquet data from a variable

Tags: python, file, variables, parquet

I am reading a parquet file and transforming it into dataframe.

```
from fastparquet import ParquetFile 
pf = ParquetFile('file.parquet') 
df = pf.to_pandas()
```

Is there a way to read a parquet file from a variable (that previously read and now hold parquet data)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas there is method to deal with parquet. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) is reference to the docs. Something like that:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_parquet('file.parquet')
```

should work. Also please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813815/how-to-read-a-parquet-file-into-pandas-dataframe) post for engine selection.

Comment: Yes. Can you, please elaborate more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Some process A reads a parquet file and have it in a Variable. Process B reads the Variable (parquet file variable). Just need to read parquet from Variable (not file).

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file from a variable also using `pandas.read_parquet` using the following code. I tested this with the `pyarrow` backend but this should also work for the `fastparquet` backend.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

with open("file.parquet", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()

buf = io.BytesIO(data)
df = pd.read_parquet(buf)
```