# AttributeError: __enter__ while using with statement with read_parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet

I want to open all parquet files existing in a specific folder and draw a scatter plot with it. I used following code:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.parquet"):
    with pd.read_parquet(file, columns=["cordx", "cordy"]) as df:
        make some scaterplot
```

Files can be found as I let python print the `file` sucessfully. But i recive `AttributeError: __enter__`. And `read_parquet` is the corredct way to open those files. When I dont use columns=[ ] I get `pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: Arrow error: Out of memory: malloc of size 9771487328 failed` error because the files are very big. So its necessary to load only those columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error tells you that `pandas.read_parquet` does not have a context manager implemented which means that you cannot call it using `with` because `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are missing. Look in here [How to read a Parquet file into Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813815/how-to-read-a-parquet-file-into-pandas-dataframe)