# Is there a Parquet equivalent for Python?

Tags: python, parquet

I just discovered [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) and it met my "big" data processing / (local) storage needs:

- faster than relational databases, which are designed to run over the network (creating overhead) and just aren't as fast as a solution designed for local storage
- compared to JSON or CSV: good for storing data efficiently into types (instead of everything being a string) and can read specific chunks from the file more dynamically than JSON or CSV

But to my dismay while Node.js has a fully functioning library for it, [the only Parquet lib for Python](https://github.com/jcrobak/parquet-python) seems to be quite literally a half-measure:

> parquet-python is a pure-python implementation (currently with only read-support) of the parquet format ... Not all parts of the parquet-format have been implemented yet or tested e.g. nested data

So what gives? Is there something better than Parquet already supported by Python that lowers interest in developing a library to support it? Is there some close alternative?

Comment: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

Comment: @DanScally thanks. I overlooked that result seeing it was from Apache thinking it was a how-to on implementing the format manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can read and write parquet with `pandas` which is commonly use for data jobs (not ETL on big data tho). For handling parquet pandas use two common packages:

- [pyarrow](https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/)
- [fastparquet](https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/)

**pyarrow** is a cross-platform tool providing columnar format for memory. Parquet is also a columnar format, it has support for it though it has variety of formats and it is a broader lib.

**fastparquet** is solely designed to focus on parquet format to use on process for python-based bigdata flows.

Comment: This post covers usage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813815/how-to-read-a-parquet-file-into-pandas-dataframe