# How to get pandas dataframe using pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert "pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame" data to pandas.
At the last line, "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Connection failed because the destination computer refused the connection" error occured.
How can I fix it?

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import sys

# spark setting
# local
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

# session
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("test_name").getOrCreate()

# file
path = "./data/fhvhv_tripdata_2022-10.parquet"
# header가 있는 경우 option 추가
data = spark.read.option("header", True).parquet(path)

# Error ocurred
pd_df = data.toPandas()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adnA4.png)

I want to convert "pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame" data to pandas.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure you're running pyspark 3.2 or higher, as that's where [koalas](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest) was added natively.

Then, Connection errors could be many things, but have nothing to do with pandas. Your code is correct. It's the network/configuration that is not. For example, on Windows, you'll need to configure external binary called `winutils`.

Note: You don't need a SparkContext here. You can pass options via SparkSession builder.

Otherwise, you're not using Hadoop. So, don't use Spark at all [How to read a Parquet file into Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33813815/2308683)